# how to combine a map in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
my_list = [
    {Fruit:Apple, Weight:"", Variety:"Green Apple", Amount:""},
    {Fruit:Apple, Weight:"1Kg", Variety:"", Amount:""},
    {Fruit:Apple, Weight:"1Kg", Variety:"", Amount:"2$"}]
```

I need the output below from the above list using python.

```
my_list = [{Fruit:Apple, Weight:"1Kg", Variety:"Green Apple", Amount:"2$"}]
```

need to combine the map and remove the empty values and for a single list of map

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: Where's the `map`? What you're showing are dicts, which are mapp*ings*, if that's what you mean. Anyway, what have you already tried, and where are you stuck? We're not here to write code for you. If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Either way, please read [ask].

Comment: All those names are undefined. Are they supposed to be strings? If so, they should be in quotes. No offense, but have you done a Python tutorial? You should probably do that first. This site isn't built to teach the basics.

Comment: @Tim Lists don't have an `update()` method. Maybe you mean `my_list[0].update(other)`.

Comment: You will have to do this by hand.  There is no automatic method of only updating from the non-empty values.

Comment: Was there an independent attempt at a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You do it by hand, row by row.  Notice that I have fixed your syntax by quoting all of the strings as well:

```
my_list = [
    {'Fruit':'Apple', 'Weight':"", 'Variety':"Green Apple", 'Amount':""},
    {'Fruit':'Apple', 'Weight':"1Kg", 'Variety':"", 'Amount':""},
    {'Fruit':'Apple', 'Weight':"1Kg", 'Variety':"", 'Amount':"2$"}
]

my_dict = {}
for row in my_list:
    for k,v in row.items():
        if v:
            my_dict[k] = v
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Fruit': 'Apple', 'Variety': 'Green Apple', 'Weight': '1Kg', 'Amount': '2$'}
```